# Is Happiness of a pokemon the same as Affection?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

OK, I just started playing Pokemon-Y. In PokemonAmie there are ways to increase the affection of your pokemon. Is this the same thing as Pokemon Happiness that is used for happiness evolutions?

If not, is there a character that tells you how happy your pokemon is?

Comment: For what isn't mentioned in the other question, there's a woman in Laverre City, in the Pokemon Fan Club who will look at your leading Pokemon when spoken to. She will tell you how happy your Pokemon is with various statements.

Comment: @Jerry: Ah! okay, thank you very much!! that helps :)